# WIX Changing default installation path

Tags: asp.net, iis, wix, wix3.8

I am creating .msi file for a web application using WIX toolset. I am able to create the file and installing too. But this is getting installed in my C: Drive. Is there any option/property so that i can install my application in my customized location. Below is my Product.wsx file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?include  "SourceFilesPath.wxi"?>
  <Product Id="{2A8ED50E-1A72-4C1C-A0B6-8CE057414C7B}" Name="TestSetUpProject" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0"
           Manufacturer="Rahul Test" UpgradeCode="fac49d06-fde2-4483-b244-025d65d0ed6b">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"
             Platform="x86" Description="Test" Comments="Test" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."
                  Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="TestSetUpProject" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentsGroup" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="TestSetUpProject" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <!--<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>-->
</Wix>
```

I tried using all the system properties from this link :
[msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa370905.aspx#system_folder_properties)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give Name to the ProgramFilesFolder:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="XXXX">
    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="TestSetUpProject" />
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I tried giving the name. Still getting the same issue :(
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="TestSetUpProject1">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="TestSetUpProject" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes you need to add Property tag with your custom path value. And then add a Directory tag with the same Id as created Property has.

You could use following code:

```
<Property Id="CUSTOMPATH" Value="YOUR_CUSTOM_FULL_PATH"></Property>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  ...
  <Directory Id ="CUSTOMPATH">
    ...
  </Directory>
  ...
</Directory>
```